# libav / FFMPEG streaming in one encoding, saving as another

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video, libav

I'm using libav on an embedded device. After some effort, I got a fragmented MPEG4 livestream going with it. I am very happy with this now.

What I'd like to do now is have two outputs from the same input. The first output is what I currently have, which is a web-quality video (lossy @ video rate) being processed in a callback and streamed somewhere. The second output should be a lossless video saved to a file at a much higher framerate.

I know I can produce the second output independently, but is there a clever way for libav to do these together? Or do I just do them both independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the question it looks like you would use the "Copy" filter.

So this may be done at the command line when using ffmpeg, or in code using libavfilter.

Here is the documentation on the Copy Filter:

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#copy

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not sure that's right. I want the outputs to have different FPS and different loss (crf) settings. The copy filter is just a straight-up copy.

Comment: Apologies. I misunderstood the language of the question. I will update my answer or delete it.  You may need to post more details, but for now, in short:

Comment: In short, at the command line you could do a copy, then a further transcode on the copied stream. In code, you would likely create another object or "context" representing the second output, (from a copy of the first), or then run a different transcode on the second object. For each frame acquired input, you would be writing out two different output frames to two different outputs.

Comment: Cheers, thanks. That makes sense. So basically I *could* do one lossless at full FPS, then transcode it to lossy at (say) 25 FPS. Do you think that makes sense though, or is it just worth using two independent encoders in libav?

Comment: Unfortunately you've reached the limit of my understanding at this point. I did something similar a while back, but I would have to look at code to refresh my memory. I am not sure what the performance difference would be, but I think that is your guide. If I can find a good code example, I will update my answer with that.